# Why is view width working, but not view height? Super new to coding and chart.js

Tags: html, chart.js

Here is the code: This is just the sample chart chart.js gives, just trying to make the size responsive. Just need it to stay proportional to screen size, that's all. Any idea why and how to fix this? Thanks!

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:50vw; width:80vw">
        <canvas id=chart width ="100" height ="100"></canvas>
        <script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'fff',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed that you didn't put quote around the value of `id` attribute:

```
<canvas id=chart width ="100" height ="100"></canvas>
```

Should be:

```
<canvas id="chart" width ="100" height ="100"></canvas>
```

Secondly, did you try to add css?

```
#chart {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```